# How to set elevation for circle imageview?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

**Requirement :** I need to set elevation shadow for circle imageview.

[image]

**Problem:**  If I set elevation for imageview shadow applied for square image. (circle shadow not applied)

I used circleimageview from this library -> https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Too many google search & SO search not able to find solution. Anyone give hint to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the CircularImageView library for circle elevation.

Library link - https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

*They give the default shadow feature*

**app:civ_shadow_radius**

Sample code

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:civ_border_color="#3f51b5"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
    app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution, Use drawable background for rounded saddow

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDrawerUser"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_avtar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile" />
```

Create `back_avtar.xml` inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I hope this will works for you.

Comment: you not understand my question. I don't ask how to set elevation. My elevation value applied for square of image. Not circle. this is my problem